# Clarification needed in the code and what is the underlying mathematics?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Needed to solve a problem to calculate

```
a^b mod p where  a,b <= 10 ^ 100000
MOD = 1000000007
```

In each test case `a` and `b` are given as string of numbers following the above limit. I tried to solve it using the code mentioned below using exponential modulation.

```
typedef long long ll;
ll modPow(ll base, ll exp, ll n) {
    base = base%n;
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (exp == 1)
        return base;
    else if (exp % 2 == 0)
        return modPow(base * base % n, exp / 2, n);
    else
        return base * modPow(base, exp - 1, n) % n;
 }

 int main() {
     ll test, i, j , k;
     string a, b; 
     ll x, y, ans;
     cin >> test ;
     while ( test-- ) {
         cin >> a >> b;
         x = 0;
         for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
             x = (x * 10 + (a[i] - '0')) % MOD;
         y = 0 ;

         for (i = 0 ; i < b.length(); i++)
             y = (y * 10 + (b[i] - '0')) % (MOD - 1);

         // cout << x <<" "<< y << endl;
         ans = modPow(x, y, MOD);
         cout << ans % MOD << endl ;
     }
}
```

I just want to know while calculating the exponent value `y`, why we have done

```
for (j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
    y = ( ( y * 10 ) + ( b[i] - '0') ) % (MOD-1); // gave correct answer
```

instead of

```
for (j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
    y = ( ( y * 10 ) + ( b[i] - '0') ) % (MOD); // gave wrong answer
```

Can anyone please clarify and explain the mathematics behind it ?

```
Sample Test Case :
INPUT :
5
3 2
4 5
7 4
34534985349875439875439875349875 93475349759384754395743975349573495
34543987529435983745230948023948 3498573497543987543985743989120393097595572309482304

OUTPUT : 
9
1024
2401
735851262
985546465
```

Comment: Have a look at Fermat's little theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Is this on the wrong site? Take away the programming element, which seems unrelated to the real question, and this seems like it should be on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordind to the generalization of the [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),

> a<sup>b</sup> mod p = a<sup>b mod (p-1)</sup> mod p

Answer (score 1):

This is because *a* ^ *b* mod *N* has a *cycle* of (at most) length *N* - 1.

```
2^n mod 5 --> 1 2 4 3 | 1 2 4 3 | 1 2 4 3 | ... (cycle of 4 with n = 0 ... 11)
3^n mod 7 --> 1 3 2 6 4 5 | 1 3 2 6 4 5 | ... (cycle of 6)
```

Thus, a^b mod N = a^(b mod (N-1)) mod N.